# Regular expression matching and remove spaces

Tags: regex, match

Please how can I get the address using regex:

```
Address             123 Mayor Street, LAG Branch ABC
```

used `(?<=Address(\s))(.*(?=\s))` but it includes the spaces after "Address". Trying to get an expression that extracts the address without the spaces.  (There are a couple of spaces after "Address" before "123")

Thanks!

Comment: The value without the space is in group 2

Comment: Your regex looks correct already...?

Comment: What are the pattern requirements? How do you know we need to stop before `Branch ABC` and not just `ABC`? You only provided the left-hand boundary, `Address` + whitespaces after it. Also, what is the programming language/tool you are using? Please share your relevant code part showing how you use the regex.

Comment: @Thefourthbird the result I'm getting has spaces before 123

Comment: @user202729 the result I'm getting has spaces before 123

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew trying to do  pattern matches for UiPath. So, VB.net I think. I need the string indicated in bold. "Branch ABC" is not inclusive, just another sentence following it.

Comment: Ok, so, if we assume you need to match up to `Branch ABC`, use `(?<=Address\s*)\S.*?(?=\s*Branch ABC)`. See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dAddress%5cs*%29%5cS.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cs*Branch+ABC%29&i=Address+++++++++++++123+Mayor+Street%2c+LAG+Branch+ABC). Note you can't test at regex101.com, it does not support .NET regex syntax. Well, you can select JavaScript option for this test though.

Comment: @greg616 You can use a capture group `\bAddress\s+([^,]+,\s*\S+)` [like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbAddress%5cs%2b%28%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b%2c%5cs*%5cS%2b%29&i=Address+++++++++++++123+Mayor+Street%2c+LAG+Branch+ABC) or [like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbAddress%5cs%2b%28.%2b%29%5cs&i=Address+++++++++++++123+Mayor+Street%2c+LAG+Branch+ABC) to capture before the last space (Click on the table tab)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot, this is really helpful. What about a case where I don't have any characters after the address, say "Branch ABC" starts on another line? The code matches just 123. How can I go about it? Thanks

Comment: If the address goes till the end of a line, just use `(?<=Address\s*)\S.*`. Please think about your requirements and put them into the question itself. It is still not clear how my suggestion "is really helpful".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My bad if I wasn't clear enough. I meant your previous comment answered my question; I just made another enquiry out of curiosity.

Comment: @greg616 I see, what about The fourth bird's suggestion?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew helped as well with another method. Captures "Address.....LAG". The entire string before "Branch ABC".

Comment: @Thefourthbird you can answer this question, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `(?<=Address(\s))(.*(?=\s))` that you tried asserts Address followed by a single whitespace char to the left, and then matches the rest of the line asserting a whitespace char to the right.

For the example data, that will match right before the last whitespace char in the string, and the match will also contain all the whitespace chars that are present right after `Address`

---

One option to match the bold parts in the question is to use a capture group.

```
\bAddress\s+([^,]+,\s*\S+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bAddress\s+` Match Address followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^,]+,` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `,` and then match `,`
- `\s*\S+` Match optional whitespace chars followed by 1+ non whitespace chars
- `)` Close group 1

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbAddress%5cs%2b%28%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b%2c%5cs*%5cS%2b%29&i=Address+++++++++++++123+Mayor+Street%2c+LAG+Branch+ABC%0d%0a) (*Click on the Table tab to see the value for group 1)*

**Note** that `\s` and `[^,]` can also match a newline

A variant with a positive lookbehind to get a match only:

```
(?<=\bAddress\s+)[^,\s][^,]+,\s*\S+
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbAddress%5cs%2b%29%5b%5e%2c%5cs%5d%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b%2c%5cs*%5cS%2b&i=Address+++++++++++++123+Mayor+Street%2c+LAG+Branch+ABC%0d%0a)